# ssh into device has "[294816] Cannot open self /home/aaa/-xxx or archive /home/aaa/-xxx.pkg"

Tags: ssh, pyinstaller, etcpasswd

I encountered a very strange issue. Tried to ssh into the device with an account.
The account related info is stored in /etc/passwd as below

> aaa:x:1000:27::/home/aaa:/usr/bin/aaa_cli.

But ssh got below error

> [294816] Cannot open self /home/aaa/-aaa_cli or archive
> /home/aaa/-aaa_cli.pkg

I have two questions. ssh behavior is very strange.
**1)why there is a dash beginning.**
2)**why /home/aaa is here**.  I know this is home directory after ssh, but is it expected that ssh use it to look for something?

More information

1We use pyinstaller for created the aaa_cli

```
1.pyinstaller -y --onefile aaa_cli.py
2.cp aaa_cli /usr/bin/aaa_cli
```

2.In the device, directly executing "/usr/bin/aaa_cli" works.